# Objects are not valid as a React child when trying to map antd Select options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm trying to ask my api for a list of ids and display them in `Select` component of antd.

```
<Select style={{ width: "100%" }}> 
    {myApi.getIds().then((result) => result.map((value) => {
        return <Select.Option value={value}>{value}</Select.Option>
    }))}                                               
</Select>
```

`value` is string.

`getIds` returns `Promise<string[]>`

This returns an error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).` But the `value` is just a string with an id. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**: Don't know if it will help anyone, but my solution, based on the accepted answer is:

```
const [ids, setIds] = useState<string[]>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    //some code
    if (!ids) {
        myApi.getIds().then((result) => setIds(result));
    }
// some code
return () => { };
}, [ids]);

// some more code
return (
    <>
    //render other elements
    <Select style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        {ids?.map((value) => {
            return <Select.Option value={value}>{value}</Select.Option>
        })}
    </Select>
    //render other elements
</>
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not complaining about `value`, it's complaining about the the return value of `then`.

```
<Select style={{ width: "100%" }}> 
    {myApi.getIds().then((result) => result.map((value) => {
// −^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return <Select.Option value={value}>{value}</Select.Option>
    }))}                                               
</Select>
```

The return value of `then` is a promise.

You can't render the result of calling `getIds` like that. Instead, you'll need to either:

1. Do the `getIds` in the parent component and have that component pass the result (when it's available) to this component as a prop,

   or
2. Have this component do `getIds` and wait for the result in a `useEffect` callback (functional component w/hooks) or `componentDidMount` (`class` component), save the result in state, and use that state when rendering. The component will have to handle rendering when it doesn't have the information yet.